# Скрипт лунной фазы

Tags: php, javascript, html, функции

Картинки к коду находятся в папке `../images/lunar/...`

Сам скрипт находится в `lunar.php` файле, я скопировал всё содержимое файла.

Код должен отображать дату, время и в зависимости от неё выводить предложение и соответствующую картинку Луны.
Но при запуске кода не отоброжается ничего вообще.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```html
<SCRIPT>
function getMoonAge(year, month, day)
{ 
 d = Math.floor(year/20)
 r = year-(d*20) //r is the remainder of (year/20)

 while (r>9)
 { 
  r = r-19
 }

 r = r*11

 while (r>29)
 { 
  r = r-30
 }

 if (month<3)
 { 
  month = month+2
 }

 r = r+month+day

 if (year<100)
 { 
  r = r-4
 }
 else
 {
  r = r-8.3
 }

 while(r>29)
 { 
  r = r-30
 }

 while(r<0)
 { 
  r = r+30
 }

 return r
}
  
function getMoonPhase(moonAge)
{ 
 if (moonAge<1) return "New"
 if (moonAge<6) return "Waxing Cresent"
 if (moonAge<9) return "First Quarter"
 if (moonAge<13) return "Waxing Gibbous"
 if (moonAge<16) return "Full"
 if (moonAge<20) return "Waning Gibbous"
 if (moonAge<23) return "Last Quarter"
 if (moonAge<25) return "Waning Cresent"
 if (moonAge<29) return "Waning Cresent"
 if (moonAge<1) return "New"
}

function getMoonPhaseImg(moonAge)
{ 
 if (moonAge<1) return "New"
 if (moonAge<5) return "Waxing_Cresent"
 if (moonAge<9) return "First_Quarter"
 if (moonAge<13) return "Waxing_Gibbous"
 if (moonAge<16) return "Full"
 if (moonAge<20) return "Waning_Gibbous"
 if (moonAge<22) return "Last_Quarter"
 if (moonAge<25) return "Waning_Cresent"
 if (moonAge<29) return "Waning_Cresent"
 if (moonAge<30) return "New"
}


monthNames = new Array(13)
monthNames[1]  = "Jan"
monthNames[2]  = "Feb"
monthNames[3]  = "March"
monthNames[4]  = "April"
monthNames[5]  = "May"
monthNames[6]  = "June"
monthNames[7]  = "July"
monthNames[8]  = "August"
monthNames[9]  = "Sept"
monthNames[10] = "Oct"
monthNames[11] = "Nov"
monthNames[12] = "Dec"
   
dayNames = new Array(8)
dayNames[1]  = "Sunday"
dayNames[2]  = "Monday"
dayNames[3]  = "Tuesday"
dayNames[4]  = "Wednesday"
dayNames[5]  = "Thursday"
dayNames[6]  = "Friday"
dayNames[7]  = "Saturday"
   
function getLongDate(dateObj)
{ 
 theDay = dayNames[dateObj.getDay()+1]
 theMonth = monthNames[dateObj.getMonth()+1]
 theDate = dateObj.getDate()
 
 return ""+theDay+", "+theMonth+"  "+theDate
}
  
function getNextFull(moonAge)
{ 
 currMilSecs = (new Date()).getTime()
 daysToGo = 15 - moonAge
 while(daysToGo<2)
 { 
  daysToGo = daysToGo+29
 }
 milSecsToGo = daysToGo*24*60*60*1000
 nextMoonTime = currMilSecs+milSecsToGo
 nextMoonDate = new Date(nextMoonTime)
 return nextMoonDate
}
  
function getNextNew(moonAge)
{ 
 currMilSecs = (new Date()).getTime()
 daysToGo = 29 - moonAge
 while(daysToGo<2)
 { 
  daysToGo = daysToGo+29
 }
 milSecsToGo = daysToGo*24*60*60*1000
 nextMoonTime = currMilSecs+milSecsToGo
 nextMoonDate = new Date(nextMoonTime)
 return nextMoonDate
}

</SCRIPT>

<?php
function phpblock_getMoon()
{

// The "Moon Type" Calendar

$today = getdate(); 
$month = $today['month']; 
$day = $today['mday']; 
$year = $today['year']; 
$doy = $today['yday'];

// January
if ($month == "January")
{
$moon = "This is the Wolf Moon";
}
// February
if ($month == "Fe8bruary")
{
$moon = "This is the Snow Moon";
}
// March
if ($month == "March")
{
$moon = "This is the Storm Moon";
}
// April
if ($month == "April")
{
$moon = "This is the Growing Moon";
}
// May
if ($month == "May")
{
$moon = "This is the Hare Moon";
}
// June
if ($month == "June")
{
$moon = "This is the Mead Moon";
}
// July
if ($month == "July")
{
$moon = "This is the Hay Moon";
}
// August
if ($month == "August")
{
$moon = "This is the Corn Moon";
}
// September
if ($month == "September")
{
$moon = "This is the Harvest Moon";
}
// October
if ($month == "October")
{
$moon = "This is the Blood Moon";
}
// November
if ($month == "November")
{
$moon = "This is the Snow Moon";
}
// December
if ($month == "December")
{
$moon = "This is the Cold Moon";
}

$imgstring = "<script>
 theDate = new Date();
 theYear = theDate.getYear();
 theMonth = theDate.getMonth()+1;theDay = theDate.getDate();
 theMoonAge = getMoonAge(theYear, theMonth, theDay);
 theMoonPhase = getMoonPhase(theMoonAge);
 theMoonPhase = getMoonPhaseImg(theMoonAge);
      theNextFullMoon = getNextFull(theMoonAge);
      theNextNewMoon = getNextNew(theMoonAge);
 document.write('<div align=center><img src=/images/lunar/age_'+escape(Math.round(theMoonAge))+'d.gif>');</script></div>";

$b4string = "
<div align='center'>
<A class=reverse_headertext HREF='http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/vphase.html' target='_blank'>Current Lunar Phase</A>
<br>
<A class=reverse_headertext  HREF='http://home.hiwaay.net/~krcool/Astro/moon/' target='_blank'>$moon</a>
<br><br>
<SCRIPT>
theDate = new Date();
theYear = theDate.getYear();theMonth = theDate.getMonth()+1;
theDay = theDate.getDate();
theMoonAge = getMoonAge(theYear, theMonth, theDay);
theMoonPhase = getMoonPhase(theMoonAge);
document.write('The moon is <strong>'+theMoonPhase+'<br>');

document.write('Next <strong>full</strong> moon: ');
document.write(getLongDate( getNextFull(theMoonAge)));
document.write('<br>');
document.write('Next new moon: ');
document.write(getLongDate( getNextNew(theMoonAge) )+' ');
document.write('<br>');

</SCRIPT>";

$endstring = "</font></div>";
$lbreak = "<br><div align='center'>";
$ediv = "</div>";
$moontable_start = "<table width='175' border=0><tr><td  bgcolor=black>";
$moontable_end = "</td></tr></table>";

$retval =  $moontable_start . $imgstring . "</td></tr><tr><td><font face=Arial size=1>" . $b4string . $endstring . $lbreak . "<font face='Arial' class=reverse_headertext>" . $lphase . "</div>" . $ediv .  $moontable_end;
 
return $retval;

}
?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, спрашивайте конкретное что-то, а то глядя на эту простыню, желание помочь вообще уходит, даже если оно и было.

Comment: просто сам не могу понять где именно может быть ошибка....

Comment: если вставить в php файл, то всё станет разноцветным

Comment: а где у вас точка входа во всё это? Сплошные функции, но где хоть одна вызывается?

Comment: в конце скрипта, где идёт java script, может там я как-то неправильно написал код? особенно меня волнует строка с вызовом *return*....

Comment: Откройте для себя оператор взятия остатка от деления: `r = year % 20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед `?>` вставь `echo phpblock_getMoon();`

Код работает. Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]